# While nested lops in php fetching data from sql database

Tags: php, sql, database, loops, while-loop

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM today WHERE heading='$heading' and day='$day'";
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM today WHERE day='$day'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<div id='post'><h1>".$row["heading"]."</h1>
<aside class='related-post'>".while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
{echo'<img src='".$row["image"]."'>;}
      .</aside>}";
```

I have been using while loops for fetching data from table. My connection is working is perfect but I need another loop in the first that is not working. Isn't it the good way?

Update: I tried to finish echo and again started as follow but still an error

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<div id='post'><h1>"
     .$row["heading"].
     "</h1><div class='post-side'><img class='post-image' src='"
     .$row["image"].
     "'><div class='post-data'><p><strong>Age: </strong><span>$age</span></p><p><strong>Date of birth: </strong><span>"
     .$row["day"].
     "-"
     .$row["month"].
     "-"
     .$row["year"].
     "</span></p></div></div></div><div class='description'><p>"
     .$row["description"].
     "</p></div><div class='bottom-related'><aside class='related-post'>";
     while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
     {echo"<img src='"
     .$row["image"].
     "'>/";}.echo"</aside><aside class='ad2'>".$includead."</aside></div>";

   }
   echo "</div>";
 } else {
 echo "No table found";
 }

 $conn->close();
```

Comment: What is the output that you're getting? the problem isn't clear here

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in your code

Comment: I have posted an answer below, check it and i'm available to help you solve it if it doesn't work

Comment: regarding "Update": `;}.echo` - What's that supposed to be? It doesn't work.

Comment: unfortunately there was a dot before echo that was the only problem......... Thanks everyone. thaks @RalphMelhem your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate to a string a WHILE loop; this is wrong. 
You should echo your first part, end with it and then do your while loop, and echo the end afterwards:

Your quotes are a bit messed up as well

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    echo "<div id='post'><h1>".$row["heading"]."</h1>
          <aside class='related-post'>";

    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
    {
      echo'<img src="'.$row["image"].'">';
    }
    echo '</aside>';
 }
```

Comment: Thanks man. I just posted update but there was again a mistake. But your answer made my day.

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatene `while` with **String**, it's a syntaxic error
Also, you have a probleme when trying to echo a String, you can use this syntax:

```
echo "PHP"; // will evaluate PHP variables and whitespace inside a string
echo 'PHP'; // will evaluate nothing;
```

But you can not start flushing a string **'** and finish by **"** or vice-versa.
Here the correct code :

```
<?php
$sql        = "SELECT * FROM today WHERE heading='$heading' and day='$day'";
$sql1       = "SELECT * FROM today WHERE day='$day'";
$result     = $conn->query($sql);
$result1    = $conn->query($sql1);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<div id='post'><h1>" . $row["heading"] . "</h1><aside class='related-post'>";

        while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo'<img src="' . $row["image"] .'">';
        }
        echo "</aside>";
    }
```

Comment: Try to add a little explanation for future users

Comment: while' (T_WHILE), expecting ',' or ';' in your code on line 7

Comment: @RalphMelhem : you're right, i've added a little explanation.